# Почему я не могу импортировать модуль pynacl? (discrod.py - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynacl')

Tags: python, discord.py

```
import discord
import pynacl

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('$'):
        if message.author.voice:
            await message.author.voice.channel.connect()
        return await message.channel.send(message.author.voice.channel)
```

После запуска программы появляется ошибка `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynacl'`. Важно отметить, что pynacl уже есть в списке модулей.

Когда я устанавливаю модуль повторно `pip install PyNaCl`/`pip3 install PyNaCl`, консоль выводит, что модуль уже загружен.

Пробовал:
Перезагружать IDLE, компьютер, пробовал `import nacl` (`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nacl'`), а не `import pynacl`, переустанавливал модуль, а также использовал `import discrod.py[voice]`. Если модуль не импортировать, то выводит следующую ошибку: `RuntimeError: PyNaCl library needed in order to use voice`.

Пользуюсь IDLE Python 3.7.1

Comment: Используется ли какой-нибудь virtualenv?

Comment: Скорее всего, нет

Comment: а попробуйте как импорты как предлагается автором `import nacl.utils` и `from nacl.public import PrivateKey, Box` будет ли такое работать?

Comment: ```import nacl.utils``` не работает - ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nacl'```
```from nacl.public import PrivateKey, Box``` тоже

Comment: На английском стаке мне предложили проверить версию (```python --version```). Вывод: Python 3.6.7, а я работаю в 3.7.1. Быть может, проблема в этом? Если так, то как мне сменить версию в консоли?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короче говоря, я разобрался. Спасибо всем, кто принимал участие в обсуждении вопроса. Проблема была в том, что консоль Windows была "привязана" к версии Python 3.6.7, и все модули устанавливались на неё, а я работал в 3.7.1, соответственно, отсюда и ошибка.

Как исправил:

1. Проверил `python3 --version` и обнаружил, что консоль привязана к ней.
2. Удалил версию Python 3.6.7.
3. Столкнулся с проблемой "Fatal error in launcher".
4. Удалил из AppData\Local\Programs\Python папку Python 3.6.
5. Обновил pip и скачал pynacl.
   Готово! :D